# Lightroom - slow image transfer from tethered camera (OS X, Lightroom)

Tags: canon, lightroom

I'm asking this for a customer, so maybe I'll need some time to answer if you have any questions, because I first have to ask my customer as well ;)

I upgraded his machine to OS X 10.11.3 and Lightroom CC 2015.5 with Camera Raw 9.5. He uses a Canon EOS 7D with Firmware 2.0.5

Before I upgraded the machine from OS X 10.8 everything worked fine and the images were transferred quickly. After the upgrade the transfer got slower (it takes about 5 seconds for the preview to pop up) and in the tethering-popup a small "loading-animation" appears. It takes about 10 seconds for the complete image to be displayed. This is extremely annoying for him, because he's working with models and not static objects.

Do you have any ideas which could cause that? (I already upgraded to OS X 10.11.5 and Lightroom CC 2015.6)

Regards, Christian

Comment: This is a Mac question, not a photog. question. Try the AskDifferent group. Without knowing what CPU chip, USB drivers, RAM size, etc. this can't be answered

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely with Lightroom, which has seen significant [slowdowns](http://petapixel.com/2015/10/13/lightroom-import-is-600-slower-than-competition/) in import function.

Adobe [announced](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2015/10/lightroom-62-import-update.html) that v6.3/CC 2015.3 has been released to resolve these issues, by basically returning to its older import code.

Comment: Hi cmason and thank you for your answer. If that's the case, the faster code should be included in CC2015.5 or 2015.6 - right?

Comment: Maybe they reintroduced it in one of the succeeding versions. It wouldn't be the first time they've reintroduced a "fixed" bug.